# signalr customized push notification

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have a web application that contains users and administrators and I have a system to push notifications.

I have a database record for each notification and which user will receive this notification I want to send notification to specific user each time.

how to do it??and if the user is disconnected what is going to happen?

Comment: Have you already tried to write some code? If so, please add it to your question.

Comment: I suppose you want the notification to be sent to the user only once. The simplest way is to check on _connection established event_ if the user has any notifications to receive. If yes, get all of them in a message and send it to the user and expect an acknowledgment from him. You can consider the notification delivered when the acknowledgement for it arrives - and then you can simply mark them delvieved, or delete them. It depends on your application if you want user action to acknowledge, or it can happen as soon as the notifications are shown to the user.

Comment: Of course, you could also do all of this when the notification is posted by the administrator, so the online users would get them too, not only at logon. But that also depends on the application.